# string.join append character when null

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

I am using string.join to concatenate a string, I want to append ? whenever there is a NULL in the concatenated string.

Right now it shows up like this:

```
a,b,c,,e
```

I want to show like this:

```
a,b,c,?,e
```

linq:

```
    var listStr = (from c in cc.ccValues select c.ccValue).ToList();
    return string.Join(",", listStr);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy, you just have to make a projection of your data beforehand.

Assuming you work with an `IEnumerable<string>` as `data`:

```
// replace null with "?"
var normalizedData = data.Select(s => s ?? "?");

return string.join(",", normalizedData);
```

Comment: is there any way I can display distinct for not nulls but ? for all nulls?
so if its a,b,b,,d,,f,f it should show a,b,?,d,?,f

Comment: It's certainly possible, you should create a new question for that!

Answer (score 3):

Just replace null with "?".

```
var strings = new List<string>{"a","b","c",null,"e"};
String.Join(",", strings.Select(s => s == null ? "?" : s));
```

**Update**

To get every string only once but replace every null string with "?" you can use LINQ's `Distinct` with an custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

```
var str = String.Join(",", strings.Distinct(new NullStringsAreDistinctComparer()).Select(s => s == null ? "?" : s));
```

The comparer could look like this:

```
class NullStringsAreDistinctComparer : IEqualityComparer<string> {

    public bool Equals(string x, string y) {
        return (x == null) ? y != null : x.Equals(y, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: you know there is `??`?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair jup, but this is just an example. Maybe `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` would the the better check. Depends on what op wants.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair : in this particular case, using `?? ` leads to a lot of consécutives ? characters. I found rather hard to read when writing my own answer: `s => s??"?"` . The plain old ternary operator is perhaps better here (and it's exactly the same performance-wise)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, I do not see anything wrong in using `c==null` comparison. The meaning and the plan of execution is the same...

Comment: @dusky is there any way I can display distinct for not nulls but ? for all nulls?
so if its a,b,b,,d,,f,f it should show a,b,?,d,?,f

Comment: @user793468 you could use LINQ's [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb338049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with a custom equality comparer so that null isn't equals to null.

Comment: @MaciejLos I didn't say that there was anything wrong with the ternary operator ... I just though I should mention a shortcut for this ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair : for me, clearer is better than shorter. In this particular case, I'm not sure the ternary is clear enough. I guess it is, but I could easily be convinced the other way.

Comment: @Falanwe I have to note: it's all about personal preferences! But for me a ternary operator is one of the hardest things to read (especially the most abusive variants out there) - the most clearest thing is a simply old `if` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string a ="a,b,c,,e,f,,h";
a.Replace(",,",",?,");

output : a,b,c,?,e,f,?,h
```

**[.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yq2lfU)**

Comment: `a.Replace` will not modify the existing string `a`, it will return a new one, so `a = a.Replace(",,",",?,");`, but the proper way to do it would be to handle it in `String.Join`

Comment: And what happens if there is a non-null empty string in the input in the first place. Or worse, if some of the strings started or ended with `','`, or contaned `",,"`. This is a ugly hack, and it does not even work!

Comment: @Falanwe : offcourse there is a many other ways to do that this is one of them

Comment: @Habib Whats wrong with that a = a.Replace(",,",",?,");

Comment: @KhurramAli, with the input specified in question, there shouldn't be any problem, but imagine if the collection of string is like `{"a", "Test,Something", null, "Hi,, I have an extra comma" }`

Comment: @Habib i only suggest this trick for given input well thanks for comment